# WPF VisualStateManger - How to rewind a Storyboard or go back to previous State?

Tags: wpf, storyboard, visualstatemanager

The title describes it at best. I want to switch back to a default state after a specific State is completed. I tried this by using an EventTrigger for the Completed event of the Storyboard, but that doesn't work, because the Storyboard is in a frozen (IsFrozen) state (in order to allow cross-thread access to it) and cannot be modified.

Comment: In addition: I know I could do something like: myState.Storyboard.Completed += (s, e) => VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(myStateRoot, "DefaultState", true); from Code Behind, but I would like to leave this in the Markup-Part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `StateChangedTrigger` with the `Completed` parameter set to `true` from http://expressionblend.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Behaviors%20and%20Effects&referringTitle=Documentation

Only thing is, if you're using WPF4, you'll need the fixed code: http://expressionblend.codeplex.com/workitem/8148

Comment: So, I assume there's no already existing solution for my problem in the standard framework, right? Have to mark your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: I'm not sure if there isn't a more low level / built in solution in WPF (I only have first hand development experience with Silverlight), but this StateChangedTrigger is definitely an elegant way of doing it with minimal, readable XAML and no code at all.

Comment: I'm sure it is, but I decided to leave it at that anyway.